# Where does the $2 \pi$ come from in the Fourier Transform Equation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I was working through the Fourier transform equations that arise. I was wondering where the radical outside the integral originated from?

$\hat{f}(k) = \sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2 \pi)^{1-a}}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \, e^{i b k x}$

and

$f(x) =  \sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2 \pi)^{1+a}}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, \hat{f}(k) \, e^{-i b k x}$

I was wondering where that radical originated. I always just found these equations simply stated and could not figure out where they came from and how that term came out of the integral?

Comment: I read this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574581/fourier-transform-convention-frac1-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty-fx)  and understand the different conventions. I am curious about the origin of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Just so that you have the identity $\|f\|_2=\|\hat{f}\|_2$, called Plancherel's theorem.